# Argentina taxes

Tags: macroeconomics, international-economics

I don't understand this report http://uk.businessinsider.com/wef-27-countries-with-the-highest-tax-rates-in-the-world-2016-2

How can it be that Argentina turnover tax is 90% of income (everywhere else I have looked it says waaay less, like 3%) Also on taxes for industries, I read everywhere that is 35%, except for the report in the link.

What am I missing?

Thanks